# Need a simple circuit and IC for low voltage indicator

Tags: voltage, measurement, indicator

I have a battery operated power distribution system for some audio gear I use. I need to implement a multi-level voltage indicator via LED:

Green when the voltage is above 14VDC
Orange when the voltage is between 13VDC and 14VDC
Red when the voltage is below 13VDC

I will also implement an auto-cutout when the voltage drops below 12.5VDC.

Is there an IC that will do this for me or am I going to have to grab a microcontroller?

Comment: Are you planning to have all the colors on a single LED or on multiple discrete LEDs?

Answer (score 2):

[Try the LM3914](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf).

[Example circuit](http://www.enide.net/webcms/?page=lm3914-batmon). This outputs to 10 LEDs, but you can short groups of outputs together and operate it in "dot" mode to give you three different indicators at whatever thresholds you want.

It doesn't supply auto-cutout, but you could drive a transistor from one of the lower indicators or get a voltage supervisor IC of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three comparators in a configuration similar to

[image]

More details [here](http://www.bowdenshobbycircuits.info/window.htm)

You just need to modify the circuit slightly to reflect the transition levels you requite